# Etymology of "ნარიყალა" and "Нарын-Кала": Mongolian? Turkic?

Tags: etymology, georgian, mongolian

There are ancient ruins of fortresses in Tbilisi and Derbent which share a name.

In Tbilisi there is ნარიყალა *Nariqala* and in Derbent there is Нарын-Кала *Naryn-Kala*.

The story of the name ნარიყალა in Georgia is that it was given this name by the Mongols and that it means "little fortress".

The problem is that I can't find Mongolian words meaning "little" or "fortress" which resemble the words used in the name. But they also don't resemble Georgian words with those meanings.

I only found out about the similarly named fortress in Derbent because the Russian Wikipedia articles of each are linked. I haven't found a story about the name of this fortress.

Could these be now obscure Mongolian words or is it just that I'm using a dictionary from modern Mongolia and the Mongols responsible spoke a very different variety?

Or could it be that the Mongols took words from some third language to give this name? I know the Caucasus has had many rulers over the centuries.

Or could it be something else entirely?

Comment: Nariin in Mongolian means narrow.

Comment: @Dagvadorj the sense "narrow" is very common for places at narrow passages of a river; cp *England*, Ger *Enge*; G *Vogt*; also perhaps G *Hav*, *Habsburg*, *Hannover*. No doubt there's more along those lines. The idea is that river traffic is easy to control at those sweet spots, and that the passage is vitally important, cp *Cambridge*, and similar. I think the idiom *camel through the eye of a needle* also belongs here, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 2):

The second part is certainly from Arabic *qalʿa*, a word loaned all over the Orient.

The first part may be from a given name. Armenian has Նարին *Narin* and Turkish has *Narin*, both from Persian نارین *nārīn* ‘fresh, shining, clear, polished, elegant, adorned’. Or directly from the Persian appellative.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found half of the answer.

---

Turkish `kale` means "fortress" and comes from Arabic `قلعة`.

---

As for "nar" / "narin", that could come from a King of Georgia, [დავით VI ნარინი](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_VI_of_Georgia) *Davit VI Narini*. The story is that there were two King Davids at that time, the other being [დავით VII ულუ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_VII_Ulu) *Davit VII Ulu*, with these names meaning "junior" and "senior".

But those don't seem to be the normal Georgian words for those concepts and so far I haven't found their sources to be Turkish or Mongolian either. Another puzzle ...